# Book/source for learning bioinformatics, focused on genomics?

Tags: bioinformatics, book-recommendation, literature

Does anyone know of sources for learning bioinformatics, focused on genomics? I would like to learn a lot of skills I could apply potently in the workforce if I ever became adept at the fields. My computer science knowledge is weak, and my biology knowledge is mediocre, but I find the topics to be interesting.

I have read "The dynamic Genome, A Darwinian Approach", by Fontdevila, and it was a bit rough for me. I have also read some of a introduction to genomics textbook, by Arthur M Lesk, and found it to be very "academic".

Comment: Hi, There are some bioinformatics introductory courses on "coursera" ..cud be useful to u...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Unix and Perl to the Rescue](http://unixandperl.com/) by Keith Bradnam and Ian Korf is an excellent introductory book and guide for bioinformatics (Linux and Perl) in genomics. It includes exercises and starts with the very fundamentals. You will still need some basic understanding of genetics and biology though.

Answer (score 5):

Beginning Perl for Bioinformatics by Jim Tisdall http://shop.oreilly.com is quite good, in my opinion, and his sequel, Mastering Perl for Bioinformatics is also great. The focus is largely, but not exclusively genomics.

Answer (score 3):

Elementary Sequence Analysis by Brian Golding and Dick Morton is a good starter. Online resources can be found here:http://helix.biology.mcmaster.ca/courses.html 
Here's a great online tutorial for sequencing techniques, with introduction, examples and everything.
http://bioinf.comav.upv.es/courses/sequence_analysis/sequencing_technologies.html

Answer (score 3):

While not a book per se, the edX Lifesciences course has been really useful for me, it does a great job of covering the entire pipeline of genome analysis that one would need to use. The link containing all 8 classes is here, scroll down a bit and you can see links to all of the classes in this module:

https://courses.edx.org/courses/HarvardX/PH525.3x/1T2015/dffde833663e4f71ab64246ebe5598d1/

Answer (score 1):

[A Primer for Computational Biology](https://open.oregonstate.education/computationalbiology/) is a great open-access book with intros to Unix, R, and Python. As the title says, it's focus is computational biology (e.g., applying a variety of methods and analyses) rather than strictly bioinformatics (the development of novel methods and analyses), but I've found very valuable both for myself and for teaching others.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to take a free course on [coursera](http://coursera.org)There are many valid courses focused on bioinformatics for beginners and they offers slides, notes and everything is necessary to start. If you are looking for a nice book to get started, then I suggest you [this one](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2002/10/17/biopython.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a book being worked on by some people at biostars.  It's being constantly updated

https://www.biostars.org/p/225812/

Perl is a good place to start if you don't know any coding, but when you want to use already written libraries, you'll want to know R or python, if not both.